# Excel Plus/Minus symbol in chart legend

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a chart in Excel that plots a base set of data, and then the user can enter a percentage number into a cell, and the base data plus or minus that percent (pre-calculation), is plotted. So I want to be able to have these labeled in the legend as "Base Data, + x%, - x%" and so on. However, I have not been able to figure out how to achieve this. The x% can be any number the user decides to put in, so the legend entry needs to be dynamic, but what ends up showing is "+Sheet1!A1%", instead of, say, "+5%". Any ideas what's going wrong? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have the relevant header of the table the chart refers to be dynamic

Comment: Use a cell to construct the label required, use concatenate or &. then get the chart to read that cell for the label. If you select the y-axis label (so it has the blue circle corners) then in the formula bar type "=" and select the cell with the created label and enter. I do that to customize the x & y axis labels often.